# Update birthday with full year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a columns that is for birthday and it's varchar type, I want to change in  into date and add full year instead for only 2-digit.

if someone born on 05061985 the MySQL remove first 0 and show as 50685

Change 50685
To ==> 05061985

All users birthday are from 1900 until 1999

Comment: split in from right by 2 as each size and then append 19 on last and 0 if size of date is less than 2 then append 0

Comment: Really I don't understand, can you tell how?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do that step by step

We can have strings with len 5 or 6 so we ensure we have a len 6 string left padded with zero

```
select LPAD('50685', 6, '0');
```

Now we insert the '19' in the string between the 4th and 5th position

```
select CONCAT(LEFT(LPAD('50685', 6, '0'), 4), '19', RIGHT(LPAD('50685', 6, '0'), 2));
```

Now the last step we are going to update all the BIRTHDAY fields in the table FOOBAR

```
update FOOBAR set BIRTHDAY=CONCAT(LEFT(LPAD(BIRTHDAY, 6, '0'), 4), '19', RIGHT(LPAD(BIRTHDAY, 6, '0'), 2));
```

Anyway in this case you still have a string field, I suggest to modify the format even more to do a proper date field conversion, something like YYYY-MM-DD

```
update FOOBAR set BIRTHDAY=LPAD(BIRTHDAY, 6, '0');
update FOOBAR set BIRTHDAY=CONCAT('19' , 
                                  RIGHT(BIRTHDAY, 2), 
                                  '-', 
                                  SUBSTR(BIRTHDAY, 3, 2),
                                  '-',
                                  LEFT(BIRTHDAY, 2));
alter table FOOBAR modify BIRTHDAY date;
```